# Is is possible to do this with Subversion/SVN?

Tags: apache, svn

I'm using subversion to develop a website with a designer and I'm using a remote server to the Subversion database storage.

Now I need to make visible on the Apache(same machine that Subversion server) all the changes/commits that we make to the repository.

This is possible to do?

I have searched inside the repository files but nothing looks like the name of the files of the project(PHP Project).

Can someone give me a clue on how can I make visible the changes to the repository in a website? Is there a way to connect the changes that I do the the repository to the website?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can already browse the repository using HTTP, simply add something like [Repos Style](http://reposstyle.com/) for a nice layout and folder/file history features.

Answer (score 0):

You could shell out to svnadmin.